# Mysql multi join query with list of ids

Tags: mysql, sql, join

have 3 tables

*products_to_stores*

```
product_id | store_id
___________________
50         | 1
50         | 2
66         | 1
50         | 1
111        | 3
111        | 1
51         | 1
69         | 3
69         | 2
```

*products_to_categories*

```
product_id | category_id
____________________
50         | 69
50         | 68
50         | 40
51         | 66
52         | 55
69         | 41
111        | 40
111        | 70
```

*product_descriptions*

```
product_id | manufacturer_id (parent category id)
____________________
68         | 345
69         | 233
70         | 788
50         | 788
111        | 788
51         | 210
52         | 788
```

How to get **list of product's ids** within categories ids list 68,40,41,55,66... and with manufacturer's ids list 210,788,233.... and store_id=1 within one SQL query to avoid foreach loop with php and avoid duplicated products ids?

Comment: when you put ... after a list of categories/manufactures, you mean all the category id's or only the ones you have listed

Comment: I mean the ones listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id FROM products_to_stores p INNER JOIN products_to_categories c ON c.product_id = p.product_id INNER JOIN product_descriptions d ON d.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE 
manufacturer_id IN (210,788) AND category_id IN (40,44) AND store_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT descriptions.product_id FROM product_descriptions AS descriptions
    INNER JOIN products_to_categories AS category ON category.product_id = descriptions.product_id AND category.category_id IN (/* Your categories */)
    INNER JOIN products_to_stores AS stores ON stores.product_id = descriptions.product_id AND stores.store_id = 1
WHERE descriptions.manufacturer_id IN (/* .... */)
GROUP BY descriptions.product_id
```